# Switch javascript caindo sempre em default

Tags: javascript, html

Estou estudando js, quero fazer um conversor de segundos em minutos e horas.

Estava fazendo um teste para ver se está tudo funcionando 100% e já me deparei com um problema. Esto há quase 1 hora quebrando a cabeça. Gostaria que alguém me aponta-se onde estou errando.

```js
function timesquare()
 {
  var optionsTime = document.getElementById('optionsTime').value;
  var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;


  if (convert < 60) {
   document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
   return;
  }

  switch(optionsTime){
   case "minutes":
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
    break;
   case "hours":
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
    break;

   default:
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
   break;
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">

<br><br>

<select id="optionsTime">
 <option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
 <option id="hours">Horas</option>
 <option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<button onclick="timesquare();">Converter</button>

<br><br>

<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

Comment: Para ficar mais claro... "nos options do select, troque id para value..."

Comment: @MarceloBoni troquei e recebo o seguinte erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dozfddt8/

Comment: Me sentindo a pessoa mais burra do mundo agora, entendi onde estava errando, obrigado @MarceloBoni

Comment: Acontece :) Dica: tente sempre ler bem atentamente os manuais de estudo, use sempre referencias online para comparar com o que esta fazendo, as vezes esse tipo de coisa foge aos olhos quando somos iniciantes

Comment: Vou seguir a sua dica @MarceloBoni. Mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Além da sugestão do **MarceloBoni**  `"nos options do select, troque id para value..."`

Também é possível executar o código com ids nos options. Veja

- **exemplo 1**

```js
document.getElementById("converter").onclick = function() {
timesquare(document.getElementById("optionsTime"));
};

function timesquare(s) {

var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].id);
var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;

  if (convert < 60) {
document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
return;
  }

  switch(optionsTime){
case "minutes":
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
    break;
case "hours":
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
    break;

default:
    document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
    break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
<br>
<button id="converter">Converter</button>
<select id="optionsTime">
<option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
<option id="hours">Horas</option>
<option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

> No exemplo acima o javascript deve ser colocado após o HTML.

- **exemplo 2**

```js
function timesquare(s) {
var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].id);
var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;
 
  if (convert < 60) {
 document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
 return;
  }
 
  switch(optionsTime){
 case "minutes":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
  break;
 case "hours":
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
  break;
 
 default:
  document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
  break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
<br>
<select id="optionsTime">
 <option id="minutes">Minutos</option>
 <option id="hours">Horas</option>
 <option id="teste">Teste</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="timesquare(document.getElementById('optionsTime'));">Converter</button>
<span id="resultTime"></span>
```

> Os dois exemplos acima fazem uso da propriedade `selectedIndex` - obtém ou define o índice que especifica o item selecionado no momento, neste caso o `id`.

Antes de dar outro exemplo vou falar mais um pouco sobre essa propriedade `SelectedIndex`

Quando um usuário dá um clique em uma escolha numa lista de seleção, a propriedade `SelectedIndex` muda para um número de base zero correspondente à posição desse item na lista. O primeiro item tem o valor 0. Essa informação é valiosa para um script que precisa extrair o valor ou o texto de um item selecionado para posterior processamento.

**Também é possível executar o código com values nos options. Veja**

- **exemplo 3** com `[s.selectedIndex].value)`

```js
    function timesquare(s) {
    var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].value);
    var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;
     
      if (convert < 60) {
     document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
     return;
      }
     
      switch(optionsTime){
     case "minutes":
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
      break;
     case "hours":
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
      break;
     
     default:
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
      break;
      } 
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
    <br>
    <select id="optionsTime">
     <option value="minutes">Minutos</option>
     <option value="hours">Horas</option>
     <option value="teste">Teste</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="timesquare(document.getElementById('optionsTime'));">Converter</button>
    <span id="resultTime"></span>
```

**E para finalizar, sem id e sem value nos options, pelo texto correspondente à opção**

- **exemplo 4** com `[s.selectedIndex].text)`

```js
    function timesquare(s) {
    var optionsTime = (s[s.selectedIndex].text);
    var convert = document.getElementById('convert').value;
     
      if (convert < 60) {
     document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "Escolha um valor acima de 60";
     return;
      }
     
      switch(optionsTime){
     case "Minutes":
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu minutos';
      break;
     case "Horas":
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = 'Vc escolheu Horas';
      break;
     
     default:
      document.getElementById('resultTime').innerHTML = "no result";
      break;
      } 
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="convert" placeholder="Insira os segundos">
    <br>
    <select id="optionsTime">
     <option>Minutos</option>
     <option>Horas</option>
     <option>Teste</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="timesquare(document.getElementById('optionsTime'));">Converter</button>
    <span id="resultTime"></span>
```

### Conclusão

**O seu erro não foi devido a usar `id` ou `value` nos options e sim como fazer o javascript recuperar essas informações.**

> Espero que tenha entendido e aproveito para lhe perguntar. E `selectedIndex].text="NovoTexto"` o que faria no item selecionado?

Comment: Porque o downvoto? Não gostou da aula ou não entendeu?